# how do I continue my text on single line without breaking? if text is from the center of the page

Tags: html

how do I continue my text on single line without breaking? The text starts from left side of the page with 500px. The 500px of left side of the page is used for other tags like ordered lists and tables and now I have to write the text after these 500px and the line should not break when it reaches to end of screen.I tried div and span none working. Is there a way to do it?
something like these

```
<div style="width:1000px"> ' but still not
```

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<pre>text goes here</pre>` should do it. :)

Comment: On second thought, this might produce undesirable side-effects, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden">
```